# .bat to .sh translation

Tags: sh

I'm translating a .bat to .sh to test a batch for a JavaEE program, but I still have errors. Do you know what I'm doing wrong ?

```
#!/bin/sh
# PROVIDER_URL BATCHBEAN BATCHNAME BATCHPARAMS exist

export USER_INSTALL_ROOT=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/
export PARM1=-Dcom.ibm.SSL.ConfigURL=$USER_INSTALL_ROOT/properties/ssl.client.props
export PARM2=-Dcom.ibm.CORBA.ConfigURL=file:/$USER_INSTALL_ROOT/properties/sas.client.props
export PARM3=-Dcom.ibm.CORBA.loginUserid=login
export PARM4=-Dcom.ibm.CORBA.loginPassword=psw
export PARM5=-Dcom.ibm.CORBA.loginSource=properties
export PARM=$PARM1 $PARM2 $PARM3 $PARM4 $PARM5
#   export: -Dcom.ibm.CORBA.ConfigURL: bad variable name

export CCJ_LIB=/myPath
export CLASSPATH=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/runtimes/com.ibm.ws.ejb.thinclient_9.0.jar
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH;$CCJ_LIB/myJar.jar
#   Permission denied

export MAINCLASS=com.projet.module.batch.BatchLauncher
export ALL_PARAMS=$PARM $MAINCLASS $BATCHBEAN $BATCHNAME $BATCHPARAMS

export JAVA_HOME=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/8.0
export JAVA_CMD=%JAVA_HOME%/bin/java

$JAVA_CMD -classpath $CLASSPATH -DPROVIDER_URL=$PROVIDER_URL -Djava.naming.factory.initial=com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory $ALL_PARAMS
```

I get errors on two lines for now, the two that I commented below

Comment: `%JAVA_HOME%` is for sure not known. Also the attempt to assign multiple parameters to `PARAM` and `ALL_PARMS` does not really work. You should use an array, but that does not exist in `sh`. Can you use `bash` instead? If not, have a look at [BashFAQ005](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005). Also most problems with shells can be picked up with https://shellcheck.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First error:**

```
# Incorrect
export PARM=$PARM1 $PARM2 $PARM3 $PARM4 $PARM5
```

This treats the expansion of `$PARM2` as another name to export, rather than setting the expansion of all 5 numbered parameters as the value of `PARM`. You need double quotes:

```
# Correct
export PARM="$PARM1 $PARM2 $PARM3 $PARM4 $PARM5"
```

**Second error:**

```
# Incorrect
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH;$CCJ_LIB/myJar.jar
```

This is an export command followed by an attempt to execute your Jar file as a command. The semicolon should be a colon.

```
# Correct
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$CCJ_LIB/myJar.jar
```

**Third error:**

```
# Incorrect
export ALL_PARAMS=$PARM $MAINCLASS $BATCHBEAN $BATCHNAME $BATCHPARAMS
```

As before, you are missing double quotes.

```
# Correct
export ALL_PARAMS="$PARM $MAINCLASS $BATCHBEAN $BATCHNAME $BATCHPARAMS"
```

**Fourth error:**

```
# Incorrect
export JAVA_CMD=%JAVA_HOME%/bin/java
```

`%JAVA_HOME%` is not a parameter expansion, but just a regular string. As you have correct expansions else where, this just looks like an oversight.

```
# Correct
export JAVA_CMD=$JAVA_HOME/bin/java
```